# Ajax pagination in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I copied this code from a website for using ajax jquery pagination in php with mysql. I have a mysql  table with 5 columns. I want to show all columns of the mysql table - not only two.

I edited the while loop but I cannot insert more columns. Please help me - I am new here and it may be difficult to understand my question. sorry in advance.

[image]

```
$query_pag_data = "SELECT * from ebook LIMIT $start, $per_page";
$result_pag_data = mysql_query($query_pag_data) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());
$msg = "";


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_data)) {


$htmlmsg=htmlentities($row['title']); //HTML entries filter
$msg .= "<li><b>" . $row['id'] . "</b> " . $htmlmsg . "</li>";

}


$msg = "<div class='data'><ul>" . $msg . "</ul></div>"; // Content for Data
```

I have linked all code

http://www.9lessons.info/2010/10/pagination-with-jquery-php-ajax-and.html

Comment: you are rendering here only 2 entities from mysql table. put each and every values in your while loop as you did it for title and id.

Answer (score 0):

You only show `$row['id']` and `$row['title']`, just add some extra with the row names ;)

Example:

```
$msg .= "<li><b>" . $row['id'] . "</b> <i>" . $row['another_row_name'] . "</i>" . $htmlmsg . "</li>";
```

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's in a while loop. It actually should be.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_data)) {
    $htmlmsg=htmlentities($row['title']); //HTML entries filter
    $msg .= "<li><b>" . $row['id'] . "</b> " . $htmlmsg . "</b> " . $row['somefield'] ."</li>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The different values are accessed by the `$row` array so it depends on what your column names are for the 5 columns.

you might what something like

```
$msg .= "<li><b>" . $row['colname1'] . "</b> " . $row['colname2'] . " " . $row['colname3'] . <insert more columns here> . "</li>" ;
```

Comment: $msg .= "<li><b>" . $row['id'] . "</b> " . $row['title'] . " " . $row['link'] . "</li>" ; i add this but it show only first two column

Comment: you sure link is a valid column in the result array as $row['link'] is probably just returning an empty string